# Self-written rollout animation stuttering in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

some time ago I started to write some code in JavaScript to learn it a little bit. I picked a rollin/rollout animation as 'project'. (I know about JQuery's slideDown/slideUp, but I wanted to work with pure JavaScript.)

I finished my effect, and the result looks pretty good in all major browsers except Firefox (tested versions 22.x to the latest (25.0.1)). In Firefox, the rolling (in and out) stutters while it rolls smoothly in Chrome, Opera, and Internet Explorer.

The general approach is (unsurprisingly) to have an element's style.height (or width) attribute increased/decreased several times by some pixels over a given time. To avoid calculating sizes every time the effect takes place, I calculate them one time and place them in an array (first item (0 + stepSize), last item wanted height/width). The decrease of the element's height is done by this function:

```
var verticalRollInWorker = function(step) {
  if (step > 0) {
    $(btt).style.height = stepSizes[step - 1];

    setTimeout(function() { verticalRollInWorker(step - 1); }, delay);
  } else {
    $(btt).style.display = "none";
    $(btt).style.height = 0;
    // Enable roll out effect:
    stateChange(false);
    if (afterFullRollIn != null) {
      afterFullRollIn();
    }
  }
}
```

In the particular example, I'm using 20 steps over 400ms. The step sizes in the array are rounded to integers, that's why the last step just sets 0 - to handle rounding differences.

(For convenience, I wrote my own $(element) helper, there's no JQuery involved here.)

I tested Firefox without Add-Ons, no difference.

I highly appreciate any help you can provide :)

Comment: You probably know this, but have you considered using CSS for animations to gain general performance improvement?

Comment: Hi Shomz. Yes, I considered that, but when I started with this (a year ago - this lay around some time ;) I didn't find a cross-browser option to have the menu stay opened until one leaves it (mouseout). Hopefully it would be possible now, but I would love to learn about the issue and see it working. Thanks for your input.

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't very precise. You could try keeping track of the elapsed time between each "frame" and adjust for any latency on the next frame, or you can use something like `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` instead and see if it improves.

Comment: Well, maybe it's something you should considered for the next version because from what I can see it seems like a perfect job for CSS. :) Back to the topic, is there a live version of this so we can test it?

Comment: Sorry, at the moment there isn't one. I'm still working locally on the site this is part of. I could probably arrange for a simple version of it being available tomorrow. -- CSS: I also started to learn some Ruby on Rails, which forces me to have JQuery available due to its REST system. I guess I'll go with Jquery's slideDown/up for a possible live version, but I want to see my very own version working as it should first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that I noticed in the above code is that you used $(btt). So, every 20s when the function is iterated, the browser needs to obtain the jQuery object. You could rather store it into a variable say '**var BTT=$(btt)**;' and use this BTT. Fetching jQuery object is a time consuming task.

Since you are using setTimeout(), the function will be executed every 20ms regardless of the completion of the current execution, this may also cause a drag. As Dagg Nabbit said, you could **use setInterval()** instad of setTimeout.

Another possible reason might be **browser-reflow**. I made a personalised scrollbar, and found browser reflow was noticeably greater in my FF than Chrome or IE. This depends on the size of the element, DOM tree depth, overflow property, and more...

And again use this code and see if it is fixed. reduces the subtraction into 1 code.

```
var BTT=$(btt).get(0);
var verticalRollInWorker = function(step) {
  if (step > 0) {
    step--;
    BTT.style.height = stepSizes[step];
    setTimeout(function() { verticalRollInWorker(step); }, delay);
  }
  else {
    BTT.style.display = "none";
    BTT.style.height = 0;
    // Enable roll out effect:
    stateChange(false);
    if (afterFullRollIn != null) {
      afterFullRollIn();
    }
  }
}
```

Further Comments can be made only after seeing a live example.
Regards.

Comment: Hi BlackPanther. Thanks for your input, I'm using a variable bttObject and setInterval now. This improved the animation flow noticeably, though it's still not as nice as with the other browsers. I'll accept your answer and hope that's ok with Dagg Nabbit, because he already posted the idea with setInterval in the comments to the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome... Well at least this time, I got enough reputation to comment... :) And the courtesy goes to @Dagg Nabbit too, I've mentioned him in the answer...